# Mimic Golang-like interfaces in C++

Tags: c++

I want to implement golang like interfaces without inheritance in c++.

Eg:-

```
//interface
struct Copyable{
    void copy();
}

class Animal { //which implements the interface but doesn't inherit it.
 ....
 void copy();
 ...
}

//consumer function
void Copy(Interface<Copyable> item){
    item.copy();
}

int main(){
 Animal a;
 Copy(a);
}
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: http://wall.org/~lewis/2012/07/23/go-style-interfaces-in-cpp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use templates:

```
template <typename T>
void Copy(T item) {
    item.copy();
}
```

Then you don't need the class `Copyable` at all.

If the type `T` doesn't have a `copy()` method, it will fail to compile (as you would expect).

[C++ Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) is a proposed feature which might someday make it into the standard language, but for now is only supported by certain compilers such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Concepts.html) (6 or later).

Comment: hmm I didn't expect that. But doesn't using a Copyable increase clarity if you have multiple functions?

Comment: Thank you. Yes Concepts seems identical to my idea.